# Java Swing, making a gridlayout fill parent?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scaling

I just recently started using Swing to create GUIs for programs, and it's been pretty fun to mess around with so far. However, I'm having an issue with a JPanel with the layout set to gridLayout. Right now it looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLDOR.png]

The grid on the right is a JPanel set to a GridLayout, with each cell being a bordered JLabel. The options on the left are also inside a JPanel, and the left JPanel and right JPanel are nested in a GridBagLayout set on a JFrame.

Essentially, my problem is that I want to "scale" the grid on the right so that each cell is a certain height and width. The grid itself will have a variable number of rows and columns, which are set when the program first starts up. Eventually, I plan to have the right JPanel in a JScrollPane (if that's how that works...), so I'm not really concerned about whether or not all of the grid shows up onScreen.

I tried setting the fill value for the gridLayout to "BOTH" and it gave me the following result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4zmd.png]

This is closer to my intention, but I wanted the actual ImageIcon in the JLabels to fill the entire JLabel. Additionally, I would want the JLabels to be the same height and width. However, I don't know exactly how to do that. I've been messing around with it for a while now, and I'm not sure if I'm just too much of a noob with Swing, or if I'm missing something in the documentation. 
In the end, I'd like the grid cells to be a fixed height and width, no matter the number of cells, and no matter whether it goes offscreen or doesn't fill it.

(Also, I just thought, maybe it's not the best idea to code this and then shove it in a JScrollPane later and expect it to perform the same.... I guess I'll just see what happens.)

Comment: If use a BoxLayout in the panel you want to contents to stretch in, they will. Alternately you could use another JPanel with a box layout, and wrap your existing panel with it. Edit- they will fill their parent if they dont have a maximum / preferred size set.

Comment: Having the I ageIcon "fill" the available space isn't going to be achievable out of the box as JLabel doesn't scale the images. You could override the getPreferredSize of the "cell" components and return the values that you need

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, I'm looking into both of your responses. Mark, are you saying that I should use a box layout for each row, and have the cells for that particular row in that box layout, etc? I'm having trouble imagining how I would accomodate a grid to a BoxLayout. And MadProgrammer, your suggestion leads me to think I might not be quite comfortable enough with swing to pull this  off.

Comment: I think you should follow MadProgrammers advice, he understood your issue better than I did, and given his rep, and experience in swing, most likely has the solution you want.

Comment: Alright, yeah, I'm looking into now. Thanks for your suggestion though, Mark! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I wanted the actual ImageIcon in the JLabels to fill the entire JLabel.

Check out Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will allow the icon to resize to file the space available for the JLabel.

Comment: This is awesome and after testing it, it works perfectly as far as scaling the ImageIcon. However, the cells themselves are still skewed when there are too many cells in the panel. But hopefully that issue will be resolved after I put the grid in a JScrollPane. Thanks for posting this!